# How to rewrite a partition with another partition in the Google Big Query Table?

Tags: sql, google-bigquery

I have a partitioned table in BQ where the recent partitions data is incorrect, so I want to copy the data of the same table with partition date "2021-01-01" to the latest partition date which is "2021-01-08".

Could anyone please help me in doing this?

Comment: You can do it with DML. Delete the rows from the given partition then insert the new ones: https://cloud.google.com/bigquery/docs/using-dml-with-partitioned-tables#inserting_data_into_ingestion-time_partitioned_tables

Answer (score 0):

You can copy partitions using partition decorator.

```
bq cp 'table$20210101' 'table$20210108'
```

Then you can delete data in the old partition using partition decorator as well.

```
bq rm 'table$20210101'
```

Please note the single quotes in the command, otherwise Bash would interpret $20210101 as a variable.